# How can i use a texture .jpg image for an openGL background window in mac?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, textures

I want to set a background for an openGL window for mac. background will take a jpg or png file.

Here is my code..

```
GLuint texture; //the array for our texture

GLfloat angle = 0.0;

GLuint LoadTexture (const char * filename, int width, int height ){

//    GLuint texture;
unsigned char * data;
FILE * file;

//The following code will read in our RAW file
file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
fclose( file );

glGenTextures( 1, &texture ); 
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture ); 
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE ); 

//    // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
//    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
//                    GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
//    // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the original
//    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
//    
//    // the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
//    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
//    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
//    
//    //Generate the texture
//    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);



// select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

// when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
// when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

//    // the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

// build our texture mipmaps
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,
                  GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

free(data);

return texture; //return whether it was successful

}

void FreeTexture( GLuint texture ){
glDeleteTextures( 1, &texture );
}

void cube () {
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture ); //bind the texture

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
//glutSolidCube(2);
}

void display () {
   glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   texture = LoadTexture( "/Users/macbook/MatrixEngineClientSample/Fighters/Sunset03.jpg", 256, 256  ); //load the texture
   glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); //enable 2D texturing
//    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
//    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
  cube();
  FreeTexture( texture );
  //glutSwapBuffers();
  //angle ++;
}

void reshape (int w, int h) {
  glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  //glLoadIdentity ();
  gluPerspective (50, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0);
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit (&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
  glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
  glutCreateWindow ("A basic OpenGL Window");
  glutDisplayFunc (display);
  glutIdleFunc (display);
  glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
  glutMainLoop ();
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I want to see this image as a background of the openGL window...image is below..

[image]

but it showing this...

[image]

Comment: You need to say so much more. What fails? What do you expect to see? Where in the code do you see the problem?

Comment: FWIW, at first glance, your code is loading the bytes of the file and trying to use that as the texture bitmap. If the file is a PNG or JPG as you say, that won't work; those file types need to be decoded into bitmaps first.

Comment: @quixoto i have updated my question...can you tell me where is my problem??? can you give me any help by giving any code or link because i am little bit newer in openGL.

Comment: Right now it's in the call to `LoadTexture()`. You're passing in the path of a JPEG file, but `LoadTexture()` assumes the file is raw. You need to either pass in the path of a raw file, or you need to write some code to load a JPEG file. You can use [`NSImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read a JPEG, for example.

Comment: @user1118321 can you give me any code??? because i do not know how can i do that.

Comment: You'll need to do some reading at the link I pasted above. Once you've done `NSImage* myImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Sunset03.jpg"];` you'll need to get the bitmap image rep for it and get the pointer to the pixels from that.

Comment: @user1118321 problem is my current file is a cpp file so i can not use `NSImage` so what can i do now??

Comment: You can use CoreMedia or any one of the other ways to read an image on the Mac. You should read Apple's docs rather than asking lots of other people to tell you where everything is. Just go to developer.apple.com and search for JPEG or PNG. Or even search the docs within Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consulted [this Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html).

The problem is that the file is compressed AND has a header, and with your code you are even using part of the file header as an image source.

I would replace this code:

```
//    GLuint texture;
unsigned char * data;
FILE * file;

//The following code will read in our RAW file
file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
fclose( file );
```

With something more similar to this:

```
CFURLRef urlRef = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/macbook/MatrixEngineClientSample/Fighters/Sunset03.jpg"];
CGImageSourceRef myImageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, NULL);
CGImageRef myImageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(myImageSourceRef, 0, NULL);
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(myImageRef));
unsigned char *data = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
```

You may need to add Core Graphics and Core Foundation to the list of your linked frameworks.

Comment: To my knowledge you are trying to add Objective-C code to a C++ project. I don't think this will work.

Comment: You can mix Obj-C and C++. Xcode uses filename extensions `.hh` and `.mm` for source that uses both.

Comment: The following apple technical q&a provides sample code for understanding the format of the raw pixel data you have access to using code like that above: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

PNG and JPG images (as with most other image formats) require some form of decompression/decoding, so loading them raw from a file wont produce expected results. It should work with bmp or uncompressed tga images after reading the file header though :/ . Anyway, here are a few image loading libraries that should make loading images easy:

[SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)

[DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/)

[GLI](http://www.g-truc.net/project-0024.html)

Comment: There's no need to resort to some hard-to-compile 3rd party library when the OS supports it natively. Just use the tools Apple supplies.

Comment: i've never had a problem with any of them. What tools do apple provide?

Comment: The OS has built-in support for image formats. If you use Apple's, your users will automatically get support for any new formats Apple adds in OS updates, as well as bug fixes, etc. When you use a 3rd party library, you only get bug fixes when you re-link your app against the 3rd party library and re-release it.

Comment: so, what tool does apple provide for loading images from files?

Comment: As mentioned above, there's [`NSImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there's also [`CGImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html). (For example, you can use `CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider()`.)